Variance of asymptotic Travelling Salesperson Problem
Consider N realisations of a uniform distribution on a bounded area in R^2 (e.g., the circle (0,1)). I know that when N is large, the length of a TSP visiting all of those points becomes "proportional" to sqrt(N), thanks to the a theorem by (Beardwood et al., 1959) https://nap.nationalacademies.org/read/2026/chapter/9#110.
However, I haven't been able to find any results regarding the variance of that length. I.e., if I define X_N as the length of the TSP, is there any asymptotic result about variance(X_N)?
Thanks!
